# Jena seems to cache BIND(RAND()) Queries

Tags: sparql, jena

I am running the following query thousands of times in a row in a Java program using Apache Jena (in order to generate random walks).

```
SELECT ?p ?o  
WHERE { 
   $ENTITY$ ?p ?o . 
   FILTER(!isLiteral(?o)). 
   BIND(RAND() AS ?sortKey) 
} ORDER BY ?sortKey LIMIT 1
```

However, I always get the same set of properties and objects (even though this seems to be extremely unlikely). I suppose Jena is caching the result to the query (despite the `RAND()` component).

What is the best and most efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you use Jena as an RDF store or as a wrapper to a SPARQL remote endpoint? If the latter is the case, you might get this behaviour for instance from Virtuoso SPARQL endpoints.

Comment: No, I have a local `OntModel` against which I am querying.

Comment: What version of Jena do you use? When I run your query with the version 3.11, a different result is produced each time the query is run.

Comment: can't reproduce it either. According to code, the random generation is based on a static variable without seed, so it's impossible resp. unlikely that the same random number is generated each time. What about the rest of the code? And the data?

Comment: I think I found the most likely reason: I am running the query in a multi-threaded environment. I could imagine that the `rand` function is not implemented for such a setting. (At least it is similar in Java: You cannot use `rand.nextInt()` but have to use rather `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()` in a multi-threaded setting).